# Do we have to follow the steps for adding Eclipse ADT plugin for Eclipse ADT or is it not required?

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
On downloading the above Eclipse version, do we still have to follow the steps for adding Eclipse ADT plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just download it, extract the files, and launch eclipse. It's prebuilt for the ADT.

Edit:

To launch eclipse, you have to open up the extracted folder -> eclipse -> eclipse.exe

You can pin it to the task bar for quick access.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, click **Help**>**Install New Software**>**Add**. Enter the repository URL (e.g. https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and give it a name. Then simply download the plugin via Eclipse.

For more detailed installation notes please take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download)